# How to not issue a new line in Python 3 when entering text with input()

Tags: python, command-line, input, python-3.x

I'm making a basic utility in **Python 3** where the user inputs a command and gets feedback printed out into the console. When entering data using the `input()` or `sys.stdin.readline()` functions this is what the command-line session may look like (including \r and \n characters)

```
1. What is your name:\n
2. <user input>\n
3. Your name is <variable>.\n
```

But, I would like to display a `\r` character after the user hits enter instead of the `\n` character, as shown on line 2. After the user had typed everything in and hit enter it would look like this

```
1. What is your name:\n
2. Your name is <variable>.\n
```

(because line 2 would have a `\r` character after the entered data, returning the cursur back to the far left)

Does anybody know of a way I might accomplish this?

Comment: so you are wanting to hide what the user input with the next line printed?

Comment: @cmd Essentially, yes. While also printing the next line on the same line. (this is why the `\b` character does not work)

Comment: given your other question, I'm assuming you are targetting windows?

Comment: @ThomasFenzl Yes, I'm targeting Windows, although a cross-platform method would be better.

Comment: maybe use getpass, this will hide their input as they type it though.  or clear the screen in after your input.  I don't think python has the c cursor manipulation to the detail you are looking.  I know you get good cursor control with curses

Comment: Are you trying to wipe the user's input from the display, or are you trying to not have a newline between the prompt and the user's input? Your question and your title contradict each other.

Comment: @user2357112 I was trying to clear the line after the user had entered the text. Although the same could be achieved if a newline was not printed when the user hits Enter, since new text could then be printed on top of the old text after printing a carriage return (`\r`) character.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I discovered this method although I am almost cirtain that the `msvcrt` module is for Windows only.

```
import msvcrt
import sys

def msgInput(prompt):
    print(prompt, end='')
    data= b''
    while True:
        char= msvcrt.getch()
        if char != b'\r':
            print(char.decode(), end='')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            data= data+char
        else:
            print('\r', end='')
            break
    return data.decode()
```

If anybody knows of any cross-platform methods, please share.

**Update** - Unfortunately this method has many limitations, such as the user cannot navigate the entered text with the arrow keys.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I believe I found the solution you wanted:

```
strng=input("Enter String - ")
```

Where strng is just a variable to hold the input response. This will return the string in the interpreter Enter String - (without any quote) and allow you to save the response in the variable strng.

Comment: I have long since stopped development of this project, but I believe the intent was for the user to be able to enter text (in a terminal window) and have the line the user entered the text removed once the user hit Enter. This is most definitely not possible in the Python IDLE console, but is possible in the Windows console or UNIX terminal using advanced techniques like `msvcrt` or `curses` modules.