# Python 3.x: How to undo the automatic new line that makes the input() method?

Tags: python, input

Well I have this code:

```
x = input('write something: ')
print("you wrote: ",x)
```

The result:

```
>>> write something: hello! #line 1
>>> you wrote: hello!       #line 2
```

But I'd like that line 2 was written where is line 1, I mean, overwrite line 1.
I couldn't do that because `input()` "ends" when user presses Enter which causes a new line on the console (the automatic new line described in the title).
Sorry if my English isn't good. Thanks!

Comment: With some (definitely not all) consoles, you could write control codes that erase and overwrite the previous line, but this would be console/terminal specific.  For detailed crosss-platform control of output, you need to use a cross-platform package or GUI framework, such as tkinter.

Comment: Did you take a look at that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489974/how-to-not-issue-a-new-line-in-python-3-when-entering-text-with-input seems like it's almost duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to get user input without inserting a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173850/possible-to-get-user-input-without-inserting-a-new-line)